# How to use onNewIntent while displaying list view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-intent

How do I use `onNewIntent` inside a `ListView` activity? Actually I am displaying a `ListView`, while displaying I got an event or status from the server side and then I need to make some changes inside the currently displaying `ListView`(e.g here the `ListView` is a contact list and based on event I want to change the text color of particular items as online/offline status).

So my point is, is there any way to get the status inside the `ListView` activity or `ArrayAdapter` so that I can make the changes whatever is required as my previous intent is already running I dont want to make any changes in that, does `onNewIntent` allow me to do the same that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your activity as `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in **AndroidManifest.xml** and then override `onNewIntent()` to capture new intents. Afterwards, perform your changes in list's data and finally call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to apply changes.

Comment: What if the activity extends ListActivity?  That just didn't work for me.