# ListView won't update onNewIntent()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a quite simple application that receives GCM's push notifications. There are similar questions here in SO, but [this is the only one I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500636/how-to-use-onnewintent-while-displaying-list-view) that tries to update the `ListView` in the `onNewIntent()` hook, but it wasn't helpful.

The "business logic" should be:

- If a notification is received when the application isn't in foreground, add it to the ListView (so, the ListView will have only one item).
- If a notification is received when the application is in foreground, add it to the ListView (so, it will have n>1 items).

This is the `Activity` that holds the `ListView`:

```
package ar.edu.uca.ingenieria.notificaciones;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import ar.edu.uca.ingenieria.notificaciones.adapter.NotificacionesAdapter;
import ar.edu.uca.ingenieria.notificaciones.gcm.GcmIntentService;
import ar.edu.uca.ingenieria.notificaciones.model.Notificacion;

/**
 * Main UI for the demo app.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    /**
     * Es el project number obtenido en la API Console, como se explica en "Getting Started."
     */
    String senderId;

    TextView mDisplay;
    List<Notificacion> notificaciones;
    private ListView notificacionesListView;

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    Context context;
    String regid;
    private NotificacionesAdapter notificacionesAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        senderId = getSenderId();
        intentarRegistrarGooglePlayServices();

        Notificacion notificacion = getNotificacionFromIntent();
        this.notificaciones = new ArrayList<Notificacion>();
        inicializarListView(notificacion);
    }

    private void inicializarListView(Notificacion notificacion) {
        this.notificaciones.add(notificacion);
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        notificacionesAdapter = new NotificacionesAdapter(this, this.notificaciones);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        this.notificacionesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notificaciones);
        this.notificacionesListView.setAdapter(notificacionesAdapter);
    }

    private void agregarNotificacion(Notificacion notificacion) {
        this.notificaciones.add(notificacion);
        // this.notificacionesAdapter.add(notificacion);
        this.notificacionesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Verifica si Google Play Services está instalado en el dispositivo. De ser así, intenta
     * registrarse y guarda el regid obtenido.
     */
    private void intentarRegistrarGooglePlayServices() {
        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "regid: " + this.regid);
    }

    private Notificacion getNotificacionFromIntent() {
        String tituloNotificacion = (String) getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(GcmIntentService.GCM_TITULO);
        Log.d(TAG, "Título: " + tituloNotificacion);
        String mensajeNotificacion = (String) getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(GcmIntentService.GCM_MENSAJE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje: " + mensajeNotificacion);
        // TODO esto muestra "1/1/1970" si no viene la fecha...
        long fechaMilisegundos = getIntent().getLongExtra(GcmIntentService.GCM_FECHA, new Date(0).getTime());
        Date fechaNotificacion = new Date(fechaMilisegundos);
        return new Notificacion(tituloNotificacion, mensajeNotificacion, fechaNotificacion);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check device for Play Services APK.
        checkPlayServices();
        Log.i(TAG, "regid: " + this.regid);
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent");
        this.setIntent(intent);
        this.agregarNotificacion(this.getNotificacionFromIntent());
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.apply();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service, if there is one.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(senderId);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                    // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                    // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                    // 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGcmPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    // TODO implementar esto del lado del server
    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send
     * messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the device sends upstream messages
     * to a server that echoes back the message using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
    }

    // TODO: esto no es responsabilidad de esta clase...
    // Tal vez un "setting provider" o similar
    private String getSenderId() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        return res.getString(R.string.senderId);
    }

}
```

However, although the `agregarNotificacion()` method is called with the correct notification, it won't update the ListView items.
I did quite a bit googling, and read that methods like `myAdapter.add()` should be used, but it didn't work either (that's why I left it commented).

So, in this particular situation (creating the ListView in one Activity hook, and updating it in another), how could I refresh my ListView?

Two final considerations:

1. There's a small bug: if the application is run for the first time, and a push is received then, it won't be added (since the `getNotificacionFromIntent()` method is returning an object with null fields, instead of a null `Notificacion`). I'm aware of it, but running and exiting the app is a quick possible workaround.
2. Sorry for the "spanglish": this is a university project, so I'm using Spanish names in the variables and classes. But also, there's some copy-paste involved, that I haven't refactored yet.

Any help or direction will be highly appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: How about creating a new activity for the ListView, and whenever notification is received, extract only the needed info and pass it int to a new intent and use that intent to start or restart the activity for the ListView. Do update in your new activity using the intent received instead of trying to change ListView in MainActivity. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: Do you mean having a "ghost" Activity that only listens for `onNewIntent()` calls, and a second Activity, which doesn't even override `onNewIntent()`, and holds the ListView?
I think that might work, since the second (let's call it "ListViewActivity") Activity would only add items in its `onCreate()` hook, am I right? 
However, I should keep this Activity's state now, I think.  
Anyway, thanks for the idea!

Comment: I added this line to the `agregarMensaje()` method: `this.notificacionesListView.getAdapter().getCount()` and it shows that the Adapter is holding *all* the items (including the ones that were added in the `onNewIntent()`) hook. But still the ListView shows only one item. I'm frustrated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to extend from `ListActivity`, and sending the new items via: `this.notificacionesAdapter.add(newItem)`.